# working standalone app .exe from python3 script that imports osgeo gdal?

Tags: gdal, geotiff-tiff, anaconda, python-3, py2exe

I have a script written in python 3.5 that uses osgeo gdal (1.11) to extract maps and file info from geotiff files.
I would like to compile this code to create a standalone app on windows, and I use pyinstaller (3.2) for this.

The code compiles but does not run, i get the following runtime error:

```py
File "site-packages\osgeo\__init__.py", line 15, in swig_import_helper
File "imp.py", line 296, in find_module    
ImportError: No module named '_gdal'
```

this is from compiling test1.py, which has a single line:

```py
from osgeo import gdal
```

with

```py
pyinstaller.exe --onefile --debug test1.py
```

and running the resulting test1.exe.

[other tests, not importing gdal, compile and run fine].

It seems there are problems importing osgeo libraries when compiling using pyinstaller and py2exe.

I have seen this question: [Working Windows Standalone .EXE From QGIS Python Script Using PyInstaller?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/177488/working-windows-standalone-exe-from-qgis-python-script-using-pyinstaller)
and i guess it is related but because it is specific to a qgis environment i do not know how to adapt the solution to my problem.

I have also seen there is a pyinstaller hook for osgeo libraries:
https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/1522, and
https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/ticket/6364,
and i checked i've got this hook in my pyinstaller folder, but it does not solve the import problem for me.

I have also posted to the pyinstaller mailing list but obtained no answer.

How can I obtain a working executable from a standard python script which imports GDAL ?

Comment: Gdal library is not qgis specific, it is provided by gdal***.dll. I don't know the specifics of pyinstaller because I've never used it, but I think you will have to bundle the gdal****.dll.

Comment: thanks, i've done been discussing this on the pysintaller github: https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/1522 , but still confused about how to fix it

Comment: I've found a workaround / hack to make the executable work:
simply commenting out the file `osgeo\__init__.py` and write `__version__ = '[your gdal version number, e.g. 1.11.4]'` instead.
this works because the only task of the file `osgeo\__init__.py` is to set the osgeo version with the same number as the gdal version.
then all other osgeo and gdal functions run normally.

Comment: You should convert your comment to an answer

Comment: ok, I have added it, it is really just a temporary hack though

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same issue for a script importing `ogr`, and was able to compile a working exe by adding the path to GDAL in the pyinstaller command:

```
C:\Python36\Scripts\pyinstaller.exe --onefile --windowed -p C:\Python36\Lib\site-packages\osgeo python_script.pyw
```

This is under Python 3.6.1, with GDAL 2.1.3 (all 64-bit), with pyinstaller 3.4.

Answer (score 1):

From the link you provided, you will have to specify the gdal***.dll in the setup code. This is from the link you provided.

```py
a = Analysis(['ShapeViewer.py'],
         pathex=['c:\\Users\\Daniel Stephanson\\workspace\\ShapeViewer'],
         binaries=None,
         datas=[('c:/OSGeo4W64/apps/qgis/plugins/*.dll','qgis_plugins')],
         hiddenimports=['PyQt4.QtSql','PyQt4.QtNetwork','PyQt4.QtXml','PyQt4.Qsci'],
         hookspath=None,
         runtime_hooks=None,
         excludes=None,
         win_no_prefer_redirects=None,
         win_private_assemblies=None,
         cipher=block_cipher)
```

You will have to change:

```py
datas=[('c:/OSGeo4W64/apps/qgis/plugins/*.dll','qgis_plugins')]
```

To something like:

```py
datas=[('c:/OSGeo4W64/bin/gdal*.dll','gdal')]
```

I've not tested though.

Comment: thank you, I've tried this but no luck. it seems the problem may be with a .pyd file not bundled correctly, also there may be other problems with python 3.5, or anaconda, or both.

Answer (score 1):

I'm adding this as an answer because it's a way to make the executable work, but it is really a hack :

comment out everything in the file `osgeo\__init__.py` and write `__version__ = '[your gdal version number, e.g. 1.11.4]'` instead.

This works because the only task of the file `osgeo\__init__.py` is to set the osgeo version with the same number as the gdal version. 
After doing this all other osgeo and gdal functions still run normally.

Comment: This method worked for me. Just don't comment out the section of the init file that sets the environment variables GDAL_DATA, etc.

Answer (score 1):

In case you don't want to change any **init** files in your python installation, alternatively you can just copy the _gdal library which is being loaded by your gdal import to your dist directory created by PyInstaller. You can automate this in a setup script with the lines:

```
import imp
import shutil
from osgeo import gdal
fp, pathname, description = imp.find_module('_gdal', [dirname(gdal.__file__)])

# now pathname contains the _gdal file which is being import by osgeo.gdal which is in my case:
# 'C:\\Apps\\Anaconda\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\osgeo\\_gdal.cp35-win_amd64.pyd'
# copy this file to your dist folder using shutil
dist_dir = "dist"
shutil.copy(pathname, dist_dir)
```

This approach works for me using python 3.5.3 and gdal 2.2.0