# Eliminating unused libraries from standalone Python-QGIS application package by PyInstaller?

Tags: pyqgis

We have a standalone PyQGis windows application that is packaged into a multi-file folder by PyInstaller (3.2.1). The OSGeo4W64 python environment is used in the application and the spec file is very similar to the one posted in this other question thread:

[Working Windows Standalone .EXE From QGIS Python Script Using PyInstaller?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/177488/working-windows-standalone-exe-from-qgis-python-script-using-pyinstaller)

The resulting package works fine, except its size is very large. In particular, it automatically pulled in libraries such as the following, among other things:

```
LIBEAY32.dll
libifcoremd.dll
libifportmd.dll
libiomp5md.dll
libiompstubs5md.dll
libmmd.dll
libmysql.dll
libpng16.dll
LIBPQ.dll
libsodium.pyd
libtiff.dll
wxbase28uh_net_vc.dll
wxbase28uh_vc.dll
wxmsw28uh_adv_vc.dll
wxmsw28uh_core_vc.dll
wxmsw28uh_html_vc.dll
mfc90.dll
mfc90u.dll
mfcm90.dll
mfcm90u.dll
Microsoft.VC90.CRT.manifest
Microsoft.VC90.MFC.manifest
msvcm90.dll
MSVCP100.dll
msvcp90.dll
MSVCR100.dll
msvcr90.dll
```

We removed these libraries to reduce the package size, but how to prevent the Pyinstaller from including these and other non-essential libraries or binaries in the first place? I think one way is to explicitly exclude these using the 'exclude' clause, but I am hoping there is a more systematic way to do this, for example, is there a way to signal to PyInstaller to only go after the first level of dependencies (not to include others recursively).

Comment: After many trials, I determined that the process of elimination of one group of DLLs at a time and try to install and run a batch functions did the trick for me, I was able to boil it down to a working package. So I consider this question as answered. I would like to post this as answer and close this thread.