# PyInstaller and QGIS 3.4

Tags: qgis-3, pyqgis-3, pyinstaller

Currently I am developping a standalone python app and I am now working on the packaging with PyInstaller.

Configuration :

- OS : Windows 10
- QGIS : 3.4.9
- PyInstaller : 3.5

Pyinstaller correctly finds many dependencies and manages to create an executable.

But when I run it, the output is :

```
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.4\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 627, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "qgis\gui\__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
RuntimeError: qgis._gui cannot import type '����' from PyQt5.QtCore
[6752] Failed to execute script main
```

I found that the sip folder in QGIS 3.4\apps\Python37\ contains many files that might be useful, so I manually added the content of sip\PyQt5 in the PyInstaller package with other PyQt5 stuff and the new output is :

```
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.4\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 627, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "qgis\gui\__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
RuntimeError: the PyQt5.Qsci module failed to register with the sip module
[4092] Failed to execute script main
```

Any idea about a file or folder I forgot to package ?
For PyInstaller I use a default .spec file.

Reviewing [Working Windows Standalone .EXE From QGIS Python Script Using PyInstaller?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/177488) with QGIS 2 didn't help

Answer (score 1):

Found a workaround:

I installed QGIS 3.4 LTR and pyinstaller in a miniconda environment on Windows 10.

(Add conda-forge channel to install QGIS)

I had to add the `platforms/` directory in the data section of pyinstaller `.spec` file (qt platform directory found in the conda environment `Library/` folder) for Qt to work.

Comment: Any chance you could please share your working spec file please? I am still having this problem even with miniconda.

Comment: Alas, I can't reproduce the working environment...!
I was probably lucky with a specific version of pyinstaller or QGIS or both...
As for now I ask my users to have QGIS preinstalled as a requirement, and I package my standalone python scripts in their APPDATA folder on Windows.